# Getting values between quotes from String - Java

Tags: java

How can I get the value between quotes from below string:

Actually at end of each string  below thing will attached with different parameter in Quotes:

```
Connect to Database to get data of student severity "low" priority "minor"

Connect to System API to get details severity "moderate" priority "medium"
```

The result must be:

```
severity = low
priority = minor

severity = moderate
priority = medium
```

Comment: Did you try something? If you did, please edit question to show code. If not, why not?

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you have a the upper snippet with the syntax `some text ... severity X priority Y` as input and want to get the values `X` and `Y` into the 2 variables?

Comment: yes @Japhei those 2 words will be constant severity & priority

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

```java
String string = "Connect to Database to get data of student severity \"low\" priority \"minor\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("severity \"(.*)\" priority \"(.*)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String severity = matcher.group(1);
    String priority = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and core java:

```
         String word =  "Connect to Database to get data of student severity \"low\" priority \"minor\"";
         String [] wordArray = word.split(" ");
         
         String severity = "", priority = "";
         for(int i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++) {
             if(wordArray[i].contains("severity")) {
                 severity = wordArray[i+1];
             }
             
             if(wordArray[i].contains("priority")) {
                 priority = wordArray[i+1];
             }
         }
         System.out.println(severity +" "+priority);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way to achieve that is by splitting the text at every `"` and taking the second and the fourth item:

```
String string = "Connect to Database to get data of student severity \"low\" priority \"minor\"";
String[] arr = string.split("\"");
String severity = arr[1];
String priority = arr[3];
```

Note that this way isn't secure against wrong input.